# Ruby newbie: Counter with 5 digit numbers

Tags: ruby, numbers

how would you create a counter method like this:
First: 00001, second: 00002
One-hundredth: 00100 and so on?
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is not very specific. What exactly is your problem, formatting the number? If yes, that can be done this way:

```
>> "%05d" % 5 #=> "00005"
```

For an entire range, you could map over it:

```
>> (1..10).map { |i| "%05d" % i } 
#=> ["00001", "00002", "00003", "00004", "00005", "00006", "00007", "00008", "00009", "00010"]
```

You could also create an array with default values like this:

```
>> counter = Array.new(10) { |i| "%05d" % i } 
#=> ["00000", "00001", "00002", "00003", "00004", "00005", "00006", "00007", "00008", "00009"]
```

And then access them like this:

```
>> counter[1] #=> "00001"
```